AWS MSK ServerlessCluster did not stabilize
I am using serverless framework to deploy my cloudformation resources. I am trying to create an MSK cluster, but I'm getting back
Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::MSK::ServerlessCluster' 
with identifier 'arn:aws:kafka:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/msk-cluster-dev/foobar-s1'
did not stabilize." (RequestToken: foobar, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)

Here is where I configured the resource
Resources:
  MskServerlessCluster:
    Type: AWS::MSK::ServerlessCluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName:msk-cluster-${self:custom.environment.${opt:stage}.environment}
      VpcConfigs:
        - SubnetIds: ${self:custom.environment.${opt:stage}.vpc.subnetIds}
          SecurityGroups: ${self:custom.environment.${opt:stage}.vpc.securityGroupIds}
      ClientAuthentication:
        Sasl:
          Iam:
            Enabled: true


When running serverless package I get this
    "MskServerlessCluster": {
      "Type": "AWS::MSK::ServerlessCluster",
      "Properties": {
        "ClusterName": "msk-cluster-dev",
        "VpcConfigs": [
          {
            "SubnetIds": [
              "subnet-xxxxxxxxx",
              "subnet-xxxxxxxxx",
              "subnet-xxxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "SecurityGroups": [
              "sg-xxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "ClientAuthentication": {
          "Sasl": {
            "Iam": {
              "Enabled": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

I feel like everything is configured correctly per the documentation. The subnets all have available IPv4 addresses and are in different availability zones.
